# Can I use QGIS plugins in PyQGIS as a stand alone script without iface?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, pyqgis, bing-maps

Can I use a qgis plugin especially (openlayers plugin) in stand alone pyqgis script?

I don't find examples, just code using iface but that cannot used in stand alone script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLUTION

I develop a python scritp based of the openscales plugin you can download in

https://github.com/joystor/BaseMap2Image

and you can call the scrit

./baseMap2Image.py bing_aerial -13704290 4440763 -9071872 567757 baseMap.jpeg 800 600

the coordinates are in EPSG:3857

I hope they serve