# Using PyQGIS in standalone scripts outside PyCharm and Spyder

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

Due to several reasons I sometimes want to use PyQGIS outside of QGIS, without using Python IDEs like PyCharm or Spyder.

Am trying to run Python from the OSGeo4W Shell on Windows but am constantly struggling to import PyQGIS

I found [this](https://anitagraser.com/2019/03/03/stand-alone-pyqgis-scripts-with-osgeo4w/) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231702/using-pyqgis-in-standalone-scripts-without-crashing), but the former requires using PyCharm and the second Spyder. There are some [other](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354087/using-plugin-in-standalone-pyqgis-script) questions on Stack Exchange but in most of them it is assumed that lines such as

```
import qgis.core 
import qgis.gui
```

are working, but that is precisely what is not working for me as am getting

```
>>> import qgis.core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'
```

Anyone knows how to import PyQGIS outside QGIS without using IDEs like PyCharm or Spyder?

Comment: did you see that: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22886/how-to-import-qgis-core-to-python-app?

Answer (score 4):

The following answer is for Windows:

In the installation folder of QGIS in the subfolder /bin you will find the python-qgis.bat file, which you can call with your pythonscript as parameter.
I usually use a .bat file with the following command:
`"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\bin\python-qgis.bat" process1.py`
where process1.py is my QGIS task in python

Comment: Thanks @eurojam ... I understand this method will use the python interpreter provided by QGIS installation (so any packages you could need would have to be reinstalled from that python environment). What if you already have a bunch of Python scripts and packages installed in i.e. C:\Python38, prior to QGIS/OSGEO4W installation ... and now you want to call QGIS from your old scripts? Do you know how to use import and use PyQGIS from your own Python environment?